# Loaded pytorch model gives different results than originally trained model

Tags: python, neural-network, pytorch

I trained a Pytorch model, saved the testing error, and saved the complete model using `torch.save(model, 'model.pt')`

I loaded the model to test it on another dataset and found the error to be higher, so I tested it on the exact same dataset as before, and found the results to be different:

[image: Data]

Here, there is not a lot of difference in the predicted values which tells me that the model is correct, but somehow different.

1 difference is that originally the model was trained on GPUs with nn.DataParallel, and while testing after loading, I am evaluating it on CPU.

```
model = torch.load('model.pt')
model = model.module # To remove the DataParallel module
model.eval()
with torch.no_grad():
    x = test_loader.dataset.tensors[0].cuda()
    pred = model(x)
    mae_loss = torch.nn.L1Loss(reduction='mean')
    mae = mae_loss(pred, y)
```

What could be causing this difference in model evaluation? Thank you in advance

Comment: how did you save the model? are you sure you are loading also the weights? Try to use this procedure: https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/saving_loading_models.html

Comment: @SalvatoreDanieleBianco, 
As mentioned, I simply saved the entire model using: `torch.save(model, 'model.pt')`

I think the weights are being loaded, because the results are quite similar, although I have no way to ensure that. 

Pytorch recommends we save the state_dict instead of the entire model, and I'm not sure if that's the reason for the error

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you forgot to set pytorch model for eval mode (e.i. *model.eval()*) after loading it ? That changes dropout and batch normalization layers to evaluation mode before running inference. Otherwise it generates inconsistent values such as your case.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35699665)